# How do I use a Regex search and replace?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like:

```
str = 'in europe it costs 250 eur'
```

or:

```
str = 'in europe it costs a lot (250eu)'
```

or:

```
str = 'eureka! I found it and it costs eu250'
```

or:

```
str = 'eureka! I found it and it costs 250.00eur'
```

and so on..

I want to replace both `'eu'` and `'eur'` with `'euro'` when they are followed and preceded by a non-char (`[^a-z]`) but I don't want them to be victims of replacement. How do I accomplish that using `sub` or other methods?

Comment: Please add some examples of before and after, so people can see what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: `(?<![A-Za-z])eur?(?![A-Za-z])` - this will match any `eu` or `eur` that is not part of a word. But _all_ `eu` and `eur` are also matched in this sample  string `eu eur djfhj eur eu`

Comment: @nhahtdh can I have some explanation abount '?<!' and '?!'? Thanks

Comment: @Poochie: It's zero-width negative look behind and negative look ahead. Search for those on Google, since they explain better than I can.

Comment: Btw. @Poochie - a good place to play and learn Ruby regexps quickly: http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we compile an array we use as the set of test cases:

```
test_input = ["aa 250 eu", "bb 250eu", "cc 250 euro", "dd 250euro", 
              "ee eu 250", "ff eu250",  "gg eur250",  "hh euro250"]
```

Next we try out the regexps:

```
puts test_input.map { |s| 
  # First gsub handles eur before number, second gsub handles eur after number
  s.gsub(/(eu|euro?)\s?(\d+)/, 'euro \2').
    gsub(/(\d+)\s?(eu|euro?)(\z|\s)/, '\1 euro') 
}
```

Explanation:

- `\d+` matches 1 or more digits (number)
- `\s?` matches zero or 1 whitespace
- `\z`  matches end of string

Result:

```
aa 250 euro
bb 250 euro
cc 250 euro
xx 250 euro
dd euro 250
ee euro 250
ff euro 250
```

Comment: This is a partial solution IMO, since the money may or may not have decimal point (at least in general text). The "at most one space" is a bit strict here.

Comment: @nhahtdh It works even with decimal points because of the `\d+` test..it's a convenient (intended) side-effect. However if someone writes "foo.00 eu", then that will be converted too..which might be desirable or not...

Comment: @nhahtdh Agree on the space..could be changed to `\s{0,3}` for example or even `\s*` if desired. Not sure what the requirement is..

Comment: On second though, your solution for decimal point may be sufficient. I may be thinking too much, since I take "56." and ".34" as cases to be considered, but I don't think I see much of them in general text.